# Why my index.html file looks different from local and remote server when I use rem

Tags: css

When I am using `rem` then my **index.html** file outputs different font size from local and remote server. But My browser size is both Chrome.

for example , my local server outputs **index.html** with `font-size: 14px` but my remote server outputs it with `font-size: 17px`.

Why it that happened?

Should I use `em` instead or my css is wrong?

My css file is like this...

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.page {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that that's the *only* difference between the two servers?

Comment: No, my localhost:5000 and  domain(http://pickalize.info) looks different font-size from localhost.

Comment: Try adding a fallback: font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4rem;

Comment: In the same browser?

Comment: @MoshFeu I'm experiencing the same thing. My local website and the remote one is rendered in Chrome (thus the same browser).

Comment: @gillesC Can you show me the local file and the url of the remote? I want to try to debug it by myself.

Comment: Anyone found a solution? I have this problem :(